# Regular Expressions in Javascript, Commas and Periods

Tags: javascript, regex

I was doing a favor for my friend (she wanted a website with a text converter), and I encountered a problem. For the code I have to work, it needs to split sentences by spaces, but also keep commas and periods.

EX:

Input: `"Hello, my name is Jack."`

Array Created: `["Hello", ",", "my", "name", "is", "Jack", "."]`

I assume this will require regex in order to accomplish. I am attempting to do this in JavaScript, and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: So, "array created" is the output you want or the output you currently have?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: I think OP *wants* the result listed in 'array created' in his question, but splitting just on spaces won't give him that.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution that avoids regex:

```
var str = "Hello, my name is Jack.";

//Use .replace() to place a space before each comma and period.
str = str.replace(",", " ,");
str = str.replace(".", " .");

//Use .split() with a whitespace to create your array
var stringArray = str.split(" ");
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/phg6oetz/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var myString = "Hello, my name is Jack.";

$(document).ready(function(){
  var arrSplit = myString.split(' ');
  var transform = "";

  for(v in arrSplit){
    transform += "'" + arrSplit[v].replace(',','').replace('.','') + "',";
    if(arrSplit[v].indexOf(',')>0){
      transform += "',', ";
    }
    if(arrSplit[v].indexOf('.')>0){
      transform += "'.', ";
    }
  }

  $('#output').html(transform);
});
```

Is not a regex, but maybe help you.

[jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/3uuefc6u/)

Answer (score 0):

```
([^\s\w])|\s+
```

Split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/33

Answer (score 0):

My regex isn't brilliant so I've had to use `filter` too in this example:

```
var removeSpaces = function (el) { return el !== ' '; }
var out = str.split(/\b/g).filter(removeSpaces);

// [ "Hello", ", ", "my", "name", "is", "Jack", "." ]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n5v4orod/)